# Loading data from database to List and adding it to combo box

Tags: java, swing

My target is to load values from a single column of database into a list and add them into JComboBox.

I know how to load data from database to JComboBox but i want first to to load it into list then add this list to JComboBox.

Here is the Code what i have done so far.

School List .......................

```
import Connection.Javaconnect;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class SchoolList {

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    List <String> SchoolList;

    private static SchoolList obj = null;

    private SchoolList() {
        conn = Javaconnect.ConnecrDb();
        SchoolList = new ArrayList();
        SchoolList();
    }

    public List<String> getSchoolList() {
        return SchoolList;
    }

    public void setSchoolList(List<String> SchoolList) {
        this.SchoolList = SchoolList;
    }

    public static SchoolList getObj() {
        if (obj == null) {
            obj = new SchoolList();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public void SchoolList() {
        try {
            String sql = "Select School from School order by ID";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String Class = rs.getString("School");
                SchoolList.add(Class);
            }

            System.out.println(SchoolList);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);

        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now I'm Accessing the list by getSchoolList() but im getting java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class Loadlist {

    SchoolList schoollist;

    public Loadlist() {

        SchoolList.getObj();

        System.out.println(schoollist.getSchoolList());

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Loadlist();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to do schoollist = SchoolList.getObj(); instead of just SchoolList.getObj();

Comment: You're ignoring the return result of getObj, which means schoollist in LoadList is null. You'll also want to do research into best practices into using singletons

Comment: I check it but same result also when i replace i get a warning  "Replace with class reference. "

Comment: I can't exactly run your code, but "where" do you get this warning?

Comment: That was repay to the answer of Roy Shahaf, when i change the ShoolList.getObj() to schoollist.getObj() and get warning of "Replace with class reference. " . My problem is same as stated in the question i cannot access the list from the class